# Vis js - manipulation mode event on Network Graph

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I'm working with node and edge manipulation in the network graph in vis.js.  How do I best go about disabling the physics when I enter manipulation mode to create, edit and delete nodes?

I have created a network like so:

```
  var nodes = new vis.DataSet([
    {id: 1, label: 'Node 1'},
    {id: 2, label: 'Node 2'},
    {id: 3, label: 'Node 3'},
    {id: 4, label: 'Node 4'},
    {id: 5, label: 'Node 5'}
  ]);

  // create an array with edges
  var edges = new vis.DataSet([
    {from: 1, to: 3},
    {from: 1, to: 2},
    {from: 2, to: 4},
    {from: 2, to: 5},
    {from: 3, to: 3}
  ]);


  var options = {
        interaction: {
            hover: true,
            navigationButtons: true
        },
        manipulation: {
            enabled: true,
            addNode: function(nodeData, callback) {
                network.setOptions({
                    physics: false
                });
                callback(nodeData);
            },
            addEdge: function(edgeData, callback) {

                network.setOptions({
                    physics: false
                });
                callback(edgeData);
            },
            editNode: function(nodeData, callback) {

                network.setOptions({
                    physics: false
                });
                callback(nodeData);

            },
            editEdge: function(edgeData, callback) {

                callback(edgeData);

            },

        }
    },

    layout: {
        improvedLayout: true
    },
    nodes: {
        shape: "dot",
        font: {
            size: 8
        },
        size: 5,
    },
    edges: {
        smooth: false
    },
    physics: {
        barnesHut: {
            springLength: 40
        },
        minVelocity: 0.08,
        timestep: 0.4
    }
};

 // create a network
 var container = document.getElementById('mynetwork');
 var data = {
       nodes: nodes,
       edges: edges
 };

 var network = new vis.Network(container, data, options);
```

I see there are Manipulation methods that can be called without the GUI on [vis.js network docs](http://visjs.org/docs/network/#Events).  I can't spot an `'editModeEnabled'` event. I was hoping to write something like

```
  network.on('editModeEnabled',function(params){
       //...disable physics
   });
```

Answer (score 2):

> How do I best go about disabling the physics

You can iterate over all nodes in your dataset and set them to `fixed`:

> When [fixed is] defined as an object, movement in either X or Y direction can be disabled. (http://visjs.org/docs/network/nodes.html)

```
// freeze your nodes
const updates = nodes.get().map(node => {
  ...node,
  fixed: { x: true, y: true }
});

// pass updates to your dataset
nodes.update(updates);
```

For a helpful discussion on "disabling" physics and setting nodes to fixed see [this](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/1272) github issue, it also discusses how to fix nodes after the drag event (also see this [this](https://github.com/almende/vis/issues/315) issue, note that fixed was formerly named "allowedToMove").

> I can't spot an 'editModeEnabled' event.

While vis.js informs you e.g. about drag-start/stop events, it does not, unfortunately, inform you about going or being in "manipulation" mode. A workaround is to check the dom for class names being set, e.g. check for the presence of the back button (which only appears in manipulation mode).

```
container.getElementsByClassName('vis-button vis-back').length > 0;
```

Further, you could stay informed about changes by using a [mutation observer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for your container.

[image]